# Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object in fbconnect.pages.inc on line 230

Tags: social-network

I'm using the Facebook connect module to give the users the possibility to log in in my website with their Facebook account. The configuration of the module is good, but when I click on "Log in to NameSite with Facebook account" I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object in fbconnect.pages.inc on line 230

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the app with Facebook. The current link for doing so is https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

See http://drupal.org/node/1944522.

Comment: i have created the facebook app , and tested the id and app secret .. in another platform , it works perfectly , but not with the 'facebook connect' module , steel having the same msg problem